# taking a count of numbers occurring in a column in a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the one given below. There is one column on top. There is a second column with element name given below it. I am trying to take a count of all the numbers under each element and trying to transpose the data so that the ranking will become the column header after transposing and the count will be the data underneath each rank. tried multiple methods using pandas like

`df.eq('1').sum(axis=1) 
 df2=df.transpose`

but not getting the desired output.

## how would you rank these items on a scale of 1-5

### X Y   Z

1   2   1
2   1   3
3   1   1
1   3   2
1   1   2
2   5   3
4   1   2
1   4   4
3   3   5

desired output is something like

```
   1  2  3  4  5
```

X    (count of 1s)(count of 2s).....so on

Y    (count of 1s)(count of 2s).......

Z    (count of 1s)(count of 2s)............

any help would really mean a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply the `pd.value_counts` to all columns, which will count values from all the columns and then transpose the result:

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).T

#     1   2   3   4   5
#X  4.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 0.0
#Y  4.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 1.0
#Z  2.0 3.0 2.0 1.0 1.0
```

Comment: You can use pd.value_counts

Answer (score 2):

**Option 0**
*`pd.concat`*

```
pd.concat({c: s.value_counts() for c, s in df.iteritems()}).unstack(fill_value=0)
```

---

**Option 1**
*`stack`*  preserves int dtype

```
df.stack().groupby(level=1).apply(
    pd.value_counts
).unstack(fill_value=0)
```